# Discord.js AutoRole Reaction do nothing

Tags: node.js, discord.js

my little problem is the next one :

When i react a message, my bot do nothing :D and it's not the objectives.

My events :

```js
module.exports = async(client, messageReaction, user) => {
  const message = messageReaction.message;
  const member = message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id);
  const emoji = messageReaction.emoji.name;
  const channel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.id === '739163072064651296');

  const lol = message.guild.roles.cache.get("763104201588473896"); //id role lol
  const wz = message.guild.roles.cache.get("763104236119785584"); //id role wz

  if (["lol", "wz"].includes(emoji) && message.channel.id === channel.id) {// lol = emoji name and wz too
    switch (emoji) {
      case "lol":
        member.roles.add(lol);
        message.channel.send('test')
        break;
      case "wz":
        member.roles.add(wz);
        message.channel.send('test')
        break;
    };
  };
};
```

My events handler :

```js
fs.readdir("./Events/",(error , f) => {
  if(error) console.log(error);
  console.log(`${f.length} events chargés`);

  f.forEach((f) => {
    const events = require(`./Events/${f}`);
    const event = f.split(".")[0];

    client.on(event, events.bind(null, client));    
  });
});
```

If someone can help it's perfect ! Thank you !

Comment: Are there any errors?

Comment: No... Null errors

Comment: Instead of listening to a reaction event in order to automatically add a role to a user, use a [reactionCollector](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=createReactionCollector) on the specific messages that will have the reactions on them. This works much better than your current system and will probably fix the issues you're having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to understand what you wanted to make but couln't understand you at all, your trying to make a autoRole sytem that listen's to reactions? AutoRole is supposed to be in a guildMemberAdd event, so if a member join's, you add a role automatically, but from the code you provided, it looks like it listen's to reactions on some message? If your trying to make a *Reaction Role* system, then follow [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.js-collector#reaction-role). Other than that, i can't help you.

#### If your trying to make a autoRole system follow this

From what i know, when you add a role to someone, you will have to do the following

```
member.roles.add("roleid")
```

But what your doing is basically this:

```
member.roles.add(message.guild.roles.cache.get("763104201588473896")) //as lol is defined like that
```

So, to fix it, instead of getting the role object, then trying to add the role to the user, do this, and be sure to make the file name "guildMemberAdd.js":

```
module.exports = async(client, member) => {

  const lol = "763104201588473896" //id role lol
  const wz = "763104236119785584"; //id role wz

        member.roles.add(lol);

        member.roles.add(wz);

};
```

Comment: I see, next time I will be clearer in my desires. But you have helped me a lot, thank you very much.

Comment: My pleasure, I'm always here to help!